# IIS - Serve extensionless PHP files with or without a trailing slash

Tags: php, azure, iis, web-config

I'm not very familiar IIS, but I'm trying to hide the `.php` extension from request and I also want it to work when adding a **trailing slash**.

The below works nicely to serve PHP files without the .php extension, but it does not work with a trailing slash (404).

```
<rule name="rewrite php">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).php" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
</rule>
```

What is the correct way to allow this to work with or without a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was the following:

```
<rule name="Add Trailing Slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[^/]$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".+?\.\w+$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}/" />
</rule>

<rule name="rewrite php">
  <match url="(.*)(/)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).php" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
</rule>
```

The first section forces trailing slashes for all non-directory and non-direct file requests. Notice the `<match url="(.*)(/)" />` in the second block.  This separates the trailing slash into a separate regex match group.  That way, when the file is requested *with* the PHP extension (`<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />`), the trailing slash is removed from the URI.

Comment: I had to remove this line `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).php" />`. How do i also redirect the .php file to the final url path?

Comment: @onebitrocket, In my case, the final url path was the .php filename except without the .php extension.  What are you trying to do?

The following:  `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).php" />` just tells the `rewrite php` block to ignore requests directly to `.php` files.